# AnimatedRotation not supported by flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

I worked on this about a year ago and came back to this now. I updated my flutter version and it seems that AnimatedRotation is not supported anymore. I imported all the packages but still, it won't work.

Do you have an alternative for me?
Thank you!

Comment: the error simply says that `AnimatedRotation` widget is defined in two packages that you imported and the compiler does not know which one to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a name conflict in your imports, so you have to specify what library you really want to use for unique identification to the compiler. to solve that flutter provide alias `as` `hide` and `show`

solution

```
import 'package:animated_rotation/animated_rotation.dart' as AnimatedRotation
```

You can hide the other class you don't really want. Now the compiler knows exactly which package it should use.